# My aframe code only works in Firefox and not Chrome or Safari

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, aframe

I've created sites using aframe in the past, but this time im stuck on this issue. Whenever I test my code locally it works perfectly fine in Firefox but when tested in Chrome or Safari nothing appears. I tried to host the site on Neocities.org (nightmarinparis.neocities.org) using the exact same code and nothing appears whether your on Firefox, Safari, or Chrome. Any help on what Im doing wrong would be amazing, I've been trying to figure out for hours. Heres the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>



  <title>Nightmares In Paris </title>

  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" />
```

```
<a-scene rain="" class="fullscreen" canvas="" inspector="" keyboard-shortcuts="" screenshot="" vr-mode-ui="">

    <a-assets>

    <img id="sky" src="Storm.jpg">

      <a-asset-item id="eiffel" src="eiffel.obj"></a-asset-item>

      <a-asset-item id="bat" src="bat.obj"></a-asset-item>

    </a-assets>

      <!-- Sky -->
    <a-sky src="#sky" material="" geometry=""></a-sky>

      <!-- Ground -->
    <a-plane src="grass.jpg" width="7000px" height="7000px" rotation="270 0 0" position="0 -1500 0" visible="false" material="" geometry=""></a-plane>

      <!-- Bats -->

    <a-obj-model src="#bat" position="613.517 546.477 -1655.234" rotation="-36.326 150.058 -128.801" material="color:#121212" obj-model="">
    </a-obj-model>

    <a-obj-model src="#bat" position="-909.061 546.477 -2422.7" rotation="-59.01465289847479 131.6084055415501 -112.29972784564136" material="color:#121212">
    </a-obj-model>

    <a-obj-model src="#bat" position="-122.324 -534.864 -1486.223" rotation="26.35605857601787 27.559269945792597 31.455382952682196" material="color:#121212">   
    </a-obj-model>

    <a-obj-model src="#bat" position="1786.062 368.994 -2422.7" rotation="31.341 29.049 34.549" material="color:#121212" obj-model="">
    </a-obj-model>

    <a-obj-model src="#bat" position="-234.581 1009.819 -4363.575" rotation="31.340791393656033 29.048960213132737 34.54935504638864" material="color:#121212">
    </a-obj-model>

<!-- Eiffel Tower -->

<!-- Buttons -->

    <a-entity   geometry="primitive: box; width: .08; height: 1; depth: 1" width="300px" height="100px" position="-37.789 0 -195.678" scale="0.15 0.2 3.519" 
        link="http://www.cerberus-usa.net" color="white" highlightedColor="#24CAFF">

    </a-entity>

  <!--Camera -->

  <a-camera position="2.513 3.3390000000000004 -126.624" rotation="-7.837858395959163 -529.3555633807466 0" camera="" look-controls="" wasd-controls="">

    <a-entity cursor="fuse:true;fuseTimeout:500" position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive:ring;radiusInner:0.02;radiusOuter:0.03" material="shader:flat;color:cyan"           line="end:0 0 -1000" raycaster="">

    </a-entity>

  </a-camera>

    <a-entity position="0.148 -10.937 0" scale="0.62 1 1" rain="count:10000;color:#5353ff;height:100" mixin="null"></a-entity>

   <canvas class="a-canvas a-grab-cursor" data-aframe-canvas="true" width="1366" height="41" style="width: 1366px; height: 41px;"></canvas>

   </a-scene>
```

Comment: What do the Chrome and Safari developer tools say?

Comment: I see a few issues with your code that could help troubleshoot: First, you're missing the `<body>` tag around the scene tag. Next, the eiffel.obj asseet is not loading. Did it upload it with the rest of the assets? Then I see you're using the px unit. A-Frame uses meters, so that might be a potential area to fix as well. I would start with adding the body tag first, then go from there.

Comment: Well the body and head tags are there, if you go the website and pull up the console you'll see them. the tags just didn't show in my initial post for some reason. I removed the pixel units, and eiffel.obj asset but still no luck

Comment: Strange, perhaps it didn't update on neocities? visiting on chrome view-source:https://nightmarinparis.neocities.org/ I only see the head tag, but no body tags.

Comment: I refreshed the page and now its working for some reason. When I copy and paste the exact code used on the site to check if it works locally, it still shows up blank in Chrome. Weirdest thing i've ever had to deal with lol @NoamAlmosnino

Comment: Cool, I'm seeing it work on neocities now. For the local issue, my best guesses are one - to try it in incognito mode, to make sure the old index.html is not cached. Two I'm assuming your serving it from some local server, perhaps restarting the server could help: https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/installation.html#use-a-local-server

Comment: Thanks so much man